# How to disable Plank application on Ubuntu startup

Tags: startup, ubuntu-mate, startup-applications, plank

I have installed Plank program on my Ubuntu Mate 16.04.
[Plank logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XijGZ.png)

But after first run it always run on system startup.
I don't want to uninstall it, but I want to disable startup run.
And there is no option on Ubuntu Startup Applications that I have seen.
Can anybody explain, how to disable this application on startup?

Comment: There are two ways that can be done 1) from the application itself, 2) using systemd command.

Comment: Plank is installed by default on Ubuntu Mate, so when you say you installed I wonder. And please to stop it launching at startup, right click on the plank image and click quit. That worked for me...

Comment: @George, I tried do this and it work for me only for system session. After rebootin PC it appears again. And at application has no option to disable autostart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Startup Applications, click on the application you don't want to be open at the startup then click on remove button on the right. This doesn't unistall the app, only disable the application opening on startup. In alternative you may uncheck the chekbox on the left of the application name, it works too and you can reactivate the application at startup whenever you want easily.

Edit:
if Plank doesent appear in startup application try:

```
 cd /etc/xdg/autostart/
 sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop
```

It should show all deamons at startup, also the system one.

Edit2:
with MATE Tweak go to interface->pannels and in the first select you should have selected Cupertino that has plank by default, now select MATE and plank should disappear

[image]

Comment: the problem that I have no option in Startup Applications list for Plank (I described this in question part). So I can't do this

Comment: so you have not plank in the startup application list?
Have you try to do :
cd /etc/xdg/autostart/ and
 sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop thise way you should see all startup deamons...

Comment: yea, I tried. Still no Plank option

Comment: hav you try with MATE Tweak?

Comment: I checked MATE Tweak, and it has no option. Or you mean something else?

Comment: I have added an imag to the answer... I mean that

Comment: Web Weavers, you was write about Cupertino theme. I have changed another Mate theme and no Plank after system reboot. I think, it's bad situation, and I don't no where to write about this to Plank developers.
Thanks for helping

Comment: maybe now you could install plank by apt-get or install docky that is the same dock but with more option